# Try and except for Query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to do something similar to try and except for single object .. in my situation I got a Query set and I want to do something like :

```
try:
    qs = model.objects.filter(id=1)
except qs.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http_404()
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`get_list_or_404(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) for this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

qs = get_list_or_404(model, id=1)
```

but since you are filtering on a primary key, it makes not much sense to use [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) here, you can retrieve the single `Model` object with [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

obj = get_object_or_404(model, id=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to caught an exception since none is raisen.

Why don't you try something like that?

```
qs = model.objects.filter(id=1)

if len(qs) == 0:
    raise Http_404()
```

Or, if you are not using `qs` after that, the more efficient `if qs.count() == 0:`.

Comment: Might be more pythonic to use `if not qs:`

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getObjList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       serialized_data = 
       serializers.FstObjSerializer(models.FstObjModel.objects.filter(id=2), 
       many=True)
       if serialized_data.data:
           return Response(serialized_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
           return Response({"error":"any message you want"}, 
           status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers:

```
 class FstObjSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
     model = models.FstObjModel
     fields = '__all__'
```

You can do the above